# How to implement "who is on the site" module in laravel project?

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I am using scafolding auth, and I whant to output the number of users online and a list of their nicknames on the mane page of mysite. Is there is a common way to handle this in Laravel? Can I use some middleware or something of this kind?

Answer (score 0):

May be You can try this Package

```
https://github.com/joshrainwater/active-users
```

Available in github